# How to use method(s) to add multiple, changing values

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, field

I'm working on a personal project for a friend and have hit a bit of a roadblock. I can continue as I am and write some really redundant code, but I feel there must be a more efficient way of doing this.

What I'm trying to do is write a method that will add three values and display the results to the text box under "Skill Modifier" header (see screenshot). I need to get the method, or a series of methods, to do that for each skill. It needs to get the Skill Modifier value for Balance, Climb, Escape Artist, etc...

[image: Screenshot of Skills Screen]

The method would be something like "CalculateSM"

What I have currently:

```
        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //AM + R + MM =SM
        //AM = Ability Modifier
        //R = Rank
        //MM = Misc Modifier
        //SM = Skill Modifier

        decimal balanceMod = balanceAM.Value + balanceR.Value + balanceMM.Value;
        balanceSM.Text = balanceMod.ToString();

        decimal climbMod = climbAM.Value + climbR.Value + climbMM.Value;
        climbSM.Text = climbMod.ToString();

        //etc...
    }
```

Essentially the biggest issue, for me, is figuring out how to contrive a method that can deal with so many different field names and add them in the same way. I'd like to avoid copy and pasting the same two lines of code fifty times over for each and every skill.

Any ideas would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using fields like this is not very object-oriented. you're probably going to want to introduce a Skills class that implements the method to calculate the final skill score and then use some Skills objects for different skills.

```
public class Skill
{
    int ability, rank, misc;

    public Skill(int ability, int rank, int misc)
    {
        this.ability = ability;
        this.rank = rank;
        this.misc = misc;
    }

    public int Score { get { return ability + rank + misc; }
}

Skill balance = new Skill(10, 1, 1);
textBalance.Text = balance.Score.ToString();

Skill programming = new Skill(10, 100, 0);
textProgramming.Text = programming.Score.ToString();
```

also, think of a clever way to tie the skills to your user controls. you're not going to like ending up with 50 text boxes that are all alike except for a bit of a name. a first step could be to wire them all up to the same event handler, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, the approach would be to create a class which represents one row of your skills screen.  You could then keep a list of these in some way (say, `List<Skill>`).  You could then quite easily loop through all of them:

```
foreach (Skill skill in character.Skills)
{
     // do something with the skill object
}
```

The trick would be to dynamically generate the user interface.  It's not actually very hard to do this (although a bit too much code to go into here), by far the easiest approach would be to use something like a `DataGridView`.  It should be fairly easy to google for examples, or just ask if you want specific info.

Comment: +1. If you want to keep your current UI, you could create a custom User Control which represents a row. But using a DataGridView is simpler.

Comment: Yeah, I was debating whether to give more info around that, but I think one paradigm shift per day is probably enough trouble to deal with for OP :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've been playing around a bit with the DaraGridView and am not entirely sure how you'd use a list to populate the grid? I assume I'd want to add an Object (the list?) as the datasource? I also find the controls also somewhat limiting, but that's not a big deal.  

Furthermore, @Meta, more info on paradigm #2 (custom User Control) might better suit my needs. From what I've read so far it seems... useful, to say the least. :P

Comment: @SarahMac - perhaps the DataGridView suggestion wasn't the best either, I was looking for a quick way for you to get results without having to jump through hoops.  To answer your question, you'd typically use a `BindingSource` object, and set its DataSource to the type of your Skill class (visually in VS).  The grid can be limiting at first, but is actually quite flexible after a while.  If you go the data binding route, the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface is pretty much needed.

Comment: In terms of UserControl, yes, it's a great way to go.  The additional complexity for now would be to dynamically create them and add them for each object in your list.  You'd probably want to have a container like a `FlowLayoutPanel` with the FlowDirection set to TopDown, and then just instantiate your UserControl for each skill object, pass the skill in as a parameter to the UserControl, and then add the UserControl to the FlowLayoutPanel's Controls collection.  That's a bit of a crash course, I hope it helps.

Comment: I agree with all of Daniel's points. The approach with the `UserControl`s and `FlowLayoutPanel` is the one I'd use, too.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have an object collection which you could databind to something in the UI (like a data grid or something)

Modify the values calculate things, what you could do in some example code:

```
class Skill
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string KeyAbility { get; set; }
    public int SkillModifier { get; set; }
    public int AbilityModifier { get; set; }
    public int Ranks { get; set; }
    public int MiscModifier { get; set; }

    void Calculate()
    {
        //Formula goes here
        //Set the SkillModifier
    }
}

Skill balance = new Skill() { Name = "Balance" }
```

Basically you can make a collection of skills, update through what ever UI object you bind to etc. Using fields the way you are atm is very redundant and using OO you can achieve the same with alot less work.

Basically in You'd create a collection of the Skill class, with Balance and all other skills you mentioned. Databind this collection to something in the UI, allow for updating, call different methods. You could even implement some inheritance for different type of skills. With a Skill base class.

Answer (score 0):

What type are balanceAM, balanceR etc?

Can they not derive from a base type or interface that you can use to pass to a helper method?

```
    private string GetText(IModel modelAM, IModel modelR, IModel modelMM)
{
  return  modelAM.Value + modelR.Value + modelMM.Value;
}

balanceSM.Text = this.GetText(balanceAM, balanceR, balanceMM);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the fact that you only have private fields for each individual control is your core problem. You're probably better off creating a list of structs to store them:

```
struct PickYourOwnNameHere
{
  Control SM;
  Control AM;
  Control R;
  Control MM;
}

List<PickYourOwnNameHere> skills = new List<PickYourOwnNameHere>();
```

Obviously, populate that list on initialization, and then you can just do:

```
skills.ForEach(skill =>
    skill.SM.Text = (skill.AM.Value + skill.R.Value + skill.MM.Value).ToString()
);
```

I'm doing that syntax from memory, but hopefully you get the idea.